# Do by-laws and/or articles of incorporation of a non-stock corporation need to be filed every year?

Tags: united-states, non-profit, virginia

I'm part of a group that is trying to organize as a non-profit in Virginia, and we are trying to figure out when the articles of incorporation and/or by-laws need to be filed (original/updated) with the SCC and IRS.

We're specifically thinking about whether we should put as little in them as possible and document them elsewhere so if they do need to be filed then we don't have to re-file every update.

Comment: VA SCC said they do not need to have the bylaws.